# How to use Alamofire with JSONDecoder?

Tags: alamofire, swift4

I am try to parsing google Direction API as below.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start

but unable to get any result from  JSONDecoder , it always return Error block 
I am using Alamofire code as below for parsing .

```
 let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        do {
                            let userDictionary    =  try   decoder.decode(DirectionParser.self, from: response.data!)
                        print("The Parser \(userDictionary)")

                        } catch {
                            print("Error")
                        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are doing right. Just make sure you are trying to parse what you want. You can do this by printing out

`print(response.anythingYouWant)`

Can you show us `DirectionParser`.
Make sure it is like below code

```
struct DirectionParse: Decodable {
   //things you want to fetch
}
```

P.S I would have commented if I had reputation 50+.